"How to generate and serve large dynamic sitemaps with Next.js 14 App Router?"
I'm building a search engine with a large set of media (images and videos) using Next.js 14 App Router. Due to the large number of media items, I'm facing issues with generating and serving dynamic sitemaps to ensure proper indexing by search engines.

Framework: Next.js 14 with App Router

Media: Large dataset of images and videos

Objective: Ensure all media items are indexed by search engines

Challenges: App Router does not support SSR and ISR, leading to difficulties in handling large sitemaps dynamically


What I've Tried:

Basic Sitemaps: Created sitemap.js in the app directory for main pages, but it crashes for large datasets.

Separate Sitemaps: Split sitemaps into smaller chunks for images and videos under app/media/sitemap-images.js and app/media/sitemap-videos.js, but still facing performance issues.

Configuration: Adjusted server settings and memory limits to handle large data, but it still results in "Out of Memory" errors.
Sample Code:
// app/sitemap.js
export default function sitemap() {
    return [
        {
            url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_URL}`,
            lastModified: new Date(),
            changeFrequency: "monthly",
            priority: 1,
        },
        // other static routes...
    ];
}

// app/media/sitemap-images.js
import { fetchAllImageIds } from "@/services/imageService";

export default async function sitemap() {
    const imageIds = await fetchAllImageIds();
    return imageIds.map(id => ({
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_URL}/media/image/${id}`,
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: 'monthly',
        priority: 0.8,
    }));
}

// app/media/sitemap-videos.js
import { fetchAllVideoIds } from "@/services/videoService";

export default async function sitemap() {
    const videoIds = await fetchAllVideoIds();
    return videoIds.map(id => ({
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_URL}/media/video/${id}`,
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: 'monthly',
        priority: 0.8,
    }));
}




